# Photoshop droplet not working

Tags: photoshop

i am using Photoshop cs 3 extended  in this droplet is not working,any views?

Comment: Could you add a clear description of what you are trying to do? what is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Dragged a folder onto the droplet icon. Photo shop starts running but no output came so far.
i made a action for working with a group of folder/images.
i am pretty sure that droplet actions are fine but still no output.